# Measurable set as union of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

Let $X$ be a complete separable metric space and let $\lambda$ be probability measure on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the Borel sigma algebra of $X$. I know that
$$ \lambda(B) = \sup \{ \lambda(K) \mid K \subset B, \, K \text{ compact} \} $$
for every $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$.

I would like to know under which conditions the following is true:

Given $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, there exist a family $\{K_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ of compact subsets of $B$ and a measurable subset of $B$, call it $N$, s.t.
$$ \bigcup_{n \ge 1} K_n \cup N = B, \quad \lambda(N)=0, \quad \lambda(K_i \cap K_j)=0 \text{ if } i \ne j.$$

Comment: Always true. See Billngsley's book for a proof.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have a copy of Billinsgley's book but I can't find such a proof. Would you be so kind to tell me where I can find it in the book?

Comment: I meant Billlingsley's 'Convergence of Probability measures'. I should have been more specific. The result is proved right in the beginning of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.  Define $K_n$ recursively.  Let $K_0 = \varnothing$, and by your "I know that" clause choose compact $K_{n+1} \subseteq B \setminus \bigcup_{j=0}^n K_j$ with $\lambda(K_{n+1}) \ge \frac12\lambda(B \setminus \bigcup_{j=0}^n K_j)$.  At each stage you get at least half of what is left.